# E27 NMC SMD diode

Tags: diodes

I have DRUCK UPS-III-IS Loop Calibrator to repair, and I found one faulty diode (O.L. both ways, even out of the circuit). The SMD code on it is **E27 NMC.** by ON Semi. I can't find anywhere on the internet what kind of diode it is. Being the calibrator, all elements may be crucial, to be exact, so I really don't want to mess up with any diode there. Especially if it needs to be Shottky or a particular Zener. It is connected between a Poly capacitor and in series with another (different) diode (**MX47A**) - pictures attached.

[image: Whole board faulty diode side]

[image: Part of the track in question]

[image: Faulty Diode]

Comment: D6 looks like a transzorb especially with the polyfuse next door. As for D5, it could be a bidirectional transzorb as it has no polarity marking I could see.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have confirmed that it is indeed a bidirectional diode. It's obsolete now, but I found the current replacement. About 5 years ago, ON Semi sold it to Little Fuse. The replacement is also from them.